# Real-time chat with node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am wonder which way would be better to write chat application.

First idea to send message with HTTP request, save in the database, and resend message to recipient using sockets.

Second idea is to do it using only sockets.

I wonder, because I have access and refresh token authentication system with HTTP request, and I think that this way would be safer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way works. Most people use sockets, but you can have a database to save logs and the such. Token authentication is usually done before entering the chat application, but it's up to whatever design you want. If you have no need for logs, just use normal sockets.

Comment: This is social media app, like facebook. And we get token after log in. Without it we can't use chat. I save every messages in database.

Comment: If that's the case, just go with your first plan